# Print null or transparent label in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, axis-labels, pdflatex, eps

I would like to place a few graphs beside each other horizontally. The issue is only the one at the middle should have an `xlabel`.

On implementing that, the other graphs appear to start a bit below on merging all the images together. I have tried to change the color of `xlabel`, but it hasn't been working on `epslatex`. Neither supplying a null value worked ("").

```
set format "$%g$"
set terminal epslatex size 5.25,4.2 color standalone 
set output "count.tex"

unset key
set yrange [0:18]
set xrange [0:18]
set cbrange [0:1400]
unset colorbox
set ylabel "Species 2 ----->"
set xlabel "Species 1 ----->" tc rgb "white"

plot 'combine.txt' u 1:2:3 with points pointtype 7 pointsize 3 palette
```

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: You probably want to do a `multiplot` instead of manually merging files.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround regarding this. A space could be printed instead.

```
set encoding iso_8859_1 
set xlabel "\240"
```

Answer (score 0):

Most (if not all) labels and similar can be deactivated by `unset`. So you are looking for:

```
unset xlabel
```

Comment: not really, I was looking for an invisible label or something similar to that.